# Python NameError

Tags: python, syntax

```
list1 = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z]

for item in list1:
    print item
```

Not sure why the above code is throwing this error:

```
NameError: "name 'a' is not defined"
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In addition to using quotes properly, don't retype the alphabet.

```
>>> import string
>>> string.ascii_lowercase
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
>>> L = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
>>> print L
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', ...
>>> help(string)
```

Comment: Well, a string is iterable, so one can do: for s in string.ascii_lowercase: print(s)

Comment: No need to import anything.  Just do

`[chr(i) for i in range(97,123)]`

to get all the lowercase letters in plain old python.  Or `range(65,91)` for uppercase.

Answer (score 7):

You have to put strings into (double) quotes

```
list1 = ["a","b","c",...]
```

should work

Comment: Yeah, I guess we all know beeing a blockhead... sometimes it's just too obvious :D

Comment: whether it's double or single quotes is irrelevant.

Comment: or a I sometimes like to "a b c d e".split() but for this case Roger Pate's answer is more apt.

Answer (score 2):

String literal should be enclosed in quotes :)

```
list1 = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Picking and choosing the best of the previous posts this is how I would do it since a string can be iterated.

```
>>> import string
>>> for letter in string.ascii_lowercase:
...     print(letter)
...
```

Answer (score 1):

python interprets the members in your list as variables,you shoud enclose them in

> ' or 
>   "

Answer (score 1):

Every language needs to differentiate between constants and names/variables. The most confusing is when you have to differentiate between string constants and identifiers/names/variables.

A shell (sh, bash, ksh, csh, cmd.com etc) tends to use constants; so you can just type a constant and you prefix a name/variable with a special character ($ for unix shells, % for cmd.com etc) when you want its value.

```
$ echo hello
hello
$ echo $PWD
/home/tzot
$ cd /tmp
$ cd $OLDPWD
```

Most other generic programming languages tend to use variables much more than constants, so it's the other way around: you just type the name of a variable and you (typically) enclose string constants in quotes ('', "", [] etc):

```
# assumed: a_name= "the object it points to"

>>> print ("a constant")
a constant
>>> print (a_name)
the object it points to
```

Answer (score 0):

When I need to make a list of characters, if they aren't already available in something defined in the std lib, and if I *really* need a list and not just a string, I use this form:

```
punc = list(r";:`~!@#$%^&*()_-+=[]{}\|,./<?>")
vowels = list("aeiou")  # or sometimes list("aeiouy")
```

Much simpler than all those extra quotes and commas, and it's clear to the reader that I really meant I wanted a list, and not just a string.